# Vuetify 3 select component placeholder is behaving differently as compare to Vuetify 2

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

In Vuetify 3, Passing a value in `v-model` which is not available in the `items` array, is displaying the value in `v-select`. Ideally if value is not valid, It should display the placeholder text. This is working fine in Vuetify 2.

**Current :** Vue 3 Demo (As I am passing empty string and that is not available in the items array, It should display the placeholder but it is showing an empty string selected in v-select) **:**

```js
const { createApp } = Vue
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()

const app = createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      value: '',
      items: ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Hoo', 'Coo']
    }
  }
});

app.use(vuetify).mount('#app');
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.3.13/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.3.13/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
           <h3 style="margin-bottom: 30px">Vue 3 Select Component</h3>
           <v-select
            v-model="value"
            :items="items"
            variant="solo"
            density="compact"
            rounded
            dense
            placeholder="Standard">
         </v-select>
        </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**Expected :** Vue 2 Demo (As I am passing empty string and that is not available in the items array, It is showing placeholder text) **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    value: '',
    items: ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Hoo', 'Coo']
  }),
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.7.1/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.7.1/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
           <h2 style="margin-bottom: 30px">Vue 2 Select Component</h2>
          <v-select
            v-model="value"
            :items="items"
            placeholder="Standard"
            outlined
            rounded
            dense
          ></v-select>
     </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

I can fix this by assigning a null value to the `v-model` values if that value is not available in `items` array but as I am getting the values to bind in v-model from the backend, don't want to modify them at client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reproduce the behavior of v2, you can conditionally set the input value to null if there is no corresponding option. You have to use `:modelValue` and `@update:modelValue` instead of the short-hand `v-model`:

```html
<v-select
  :modelValue="items.some(item => item.name === value) ? value : null"
  @update:modelValue="value = $event"
  ...
```

This will show the placeholder and at the same time keep the initial value until a new option is selected, just as v2 does.

```js
const { createApp } = Vue
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()

const app = createApp({
  template: `
    <v-app id="inspire">
      <v-container fluid>
             <h3 style="margin-bottom: 30px">Vue 3 Select Component</h3>
             <v-select
              :modelValue="items.some(item => item.name === value) ? value : null"
              @update:modelValue="value = $event"
              :items="items"
              item-title="name"
              item-value="name"
              variant="solo"
              bg-color="transparent"
              density="compact"
              rounded
              dense
              placeholder="Standard">
           </v-select>
           value: {{value}}
          </v-container>
    </v-app>  
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      value: 'asdf',
      items: [
        {
            name: 'Foo',
            image: 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b17065ea1655f1e3283aac8d8fc16019?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG'
        },
        {
            name: 'Bar',
            image: 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b17065ea1655f1e3283aac8d8fc16019?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG'
        },
        {
            name: 'Hoo',
            image: 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b17065ea1655f1e3283aac8d8fc16019?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG'
        },
        {
            name: 'Coo',
            image: 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b17065ea1655f1e3283aac8d8fc16019?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});

app.use(vuetify).mount('#app');
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.3.13/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.3.13/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```